# How to split 5.1/7.1 audio input to 6x mono outputs using FFMPEG source code?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, audio-streaming

I know how to achieve this by using cmd line as:

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav \
-filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE][BL][BR]" \
-map "[FL]" front_left.wav \
-map "[FR]" front_right.wav \
-map "[FC]" front_center.wav \
-map "[LFE]" lfe.wav \
-map "[BL]" back_left.wav \
-map "[BR]" back_right.wav
```

would do the job I want for me, but, how can I achieve the same in the source code itself?

I assume the trick would be to set some option for `AVCodec` context or `SwrContext` when setting up the encoder, but I cannot find any option, that should do this job for me.

I am interested just in FFMPEG solutions and how to do it using directly the source code. The original API is in C, but any, even tiny, code sample in any language highly appreciated.

I would bet on something like:
 `av_set_options_string(...)` or `av_opt_set(...)`, but I am doing something wrong using these or it is done some other way.

Comment: Have you ever used [int system(const char *command)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm)? If your example works on the command line for you, then package it  up as a string, as pass an an argument to `system()`  There is also [this approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162546/send-command-and-get-response-from-windows-cmd-prompt-silently) which allows you to launch the command in its own process to `stdin`, then capture return content (or value) from `stdout` and close process.

Comment: These are regular system calls I would expect that I can achieve the same within the process using ffmpeg API calls.

Comment: Show what you have tried using the API calls.  (if a tutorial is needed, [try this one](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/).

Comment: The real problem that I am facing is that 4th (LFE) channel is crippling my audio output as AAC codec does not support (or at last in our forked version of FFMPEG) other layouts then:
/* Supported layouts without using a PCE */
static const int64_t aac_normal_chan_layouts[7] = {
    AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO,
    AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO,
    AV_CH_LAYOUT_SURROUND,
    AV_CH_LAYOUT_4POINT0,
    AV_CH_LAYOUT_5POINT0_BACK,
    AV_CH_LAYOUT_5POINT1_BACK,
    AV_CH_LAYOUT_7POINT1,
};
So as you can see without PCE, which I did not find out how to use, I am in 6+ chanenl setups stuck with LFE.

Comment: I tried to tackle this with swr_build_matrix and swr_set_matrix with combination of changing layout to 6.0 or octagonal for 8 channels, but then encoded result was crippled and not playable. I tought that utilizing the code behind the filter could help me somehow re-map the channels, also I think that maybe I should use somehow that PCE, but I do not have any idea how to do that, as I am by no means any audio/ffmpeg expert.

Comment: If there is some way how to force LFE channel to behave as a "normal" audio channel withou cuting of the certain frequencies, all my problems would vanish, but from what I found out, that is not possible as LFE is limited to 120 Hz by ISO, so I suspect that would make even mess with HW drivers or whatever.

Comment: Lots of words, that could be greatly enhanced if they were offered along with a little code to look at.   Please edit your post to [show your attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at using the API, along with listing the specific problems in the code that are failing to behave according to your expectations.  If you don't yet have that code, you could temporarily delete the post while you are working on your code, then post it along with any problems you encounter.

Comment: If somebody else is curious how this works: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/filtering__audio_8c_source.html